# Scala to Java8 stream compatibility issue

Tags: scala, lambda, java-8, java-stream

(scala)

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("")).forEach(x => log.info(x.toString))
```

gives

```
Error:(21, 16) missing parameter type
  .forEach(x => log.info(x.toString))
           ^
```

and (java8)

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("")).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toString()));
```

works fine

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stream.forEach(x -> foo())` in java is syntactic sugar for

```
stream.forEach(
  new Consumer<Path> { public void accept(Path x) { foo(); } }
)
```

This is not at all the same as `x => ...` in scala, which is an instance of `Function[Path,Unit]`.

Try this;

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
  .forEach(new Consumer[Path] { def accept(s: Path) = println(s) })
```

Comment: `x -> foo()` is *not* syntactic sugar for an inner class. But that’s an unimportant implementation detail anyway. What’s more important, is, that it is a construct for implementing the *target type* which is `Consumer<Path>` here…

Answer (score 1):

An alternative route: instead of converting your scala function to a java consumer, you can convert the java stream to a scala stream and use normal scala functions.

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
scala> import java.nio.file._
scala> val files = Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp")).iterator.asScala.toStream
files: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.nio.file.Path] = Stream(/tmp, ?)
files.foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.12 comes with much better Java 8 interoperability, check the [Scala 2.12 announcement](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#headline-features); as a result, your code as written compiles just fine in 2.12:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("")).forEach(x => System.out.println(x.toString))
```

If you need this to work in 2.11, use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat). Here's the dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.8.0"
```

and in this case you can use it like this:

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._
Files.walk(Paths.get("")).forEach( asJavaConsumer { x => println(x.toString) } )
```